# Datatables responsive expand button not showing when first row hidden

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, datatables-1.10

I was using datatables-responsive 1.0.6. Now i upgraded to datatables-responsive 2.1.0.
And have a following problem - when second (any but not the first) set to be hidden last, the expand button doesn't appear after first element is hidden. In 1.0.6 it was working fine.
The problem is that 1.0.6 was removing and adding row into dom, and 2.1.0 just set display:none to hidden elements, but the css style from datatables-responsive doesnt account for that and only show expand button for first row and when its hidden their css rule just dont work:

> tbody > tr > th:first-child:before

What will be a good way to fix this?

Comment: You could create a empty first column. Set it to the lowest responsive priority so that it would house the expand button.